# .NET Core 7: why all second level values in appsettings.json are all empty?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I converted a .NET Core 6 to .NET Core 7 and everything works fine in Debug mode. However in Release mode I noticed that all second level values in my appsettings.json are all empty.

Here is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "appSettings": {
    "LogRetention": 90,
    "DefaultFileRetention": 90,
    "SFTP": {
      "Host": "SomeValue.Host.com",
      "Port": "22",
      "Username": "Some-User",
      "Passphrase": "",
      "FingerPrint": "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f",
      "PrivateKeyFilename": "Some-PrivateKey.ppk"
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

My AppSettings class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public int LogRetention { get; set; } = 0;                    // Number of days before deleting log files
    public int DefaultFileRetention { get; set; } = 0;            // Default value for client configuration FileRetention
    public SFTPSettings SFTP { get; set; } = new();
}

public class SFTPSettings
{
    public string Host { get; set; } = "";
    public int Port { get; set; } = 22;
    public string Username { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    public string Passphrase { get; set; } = "";
    public string FingerPrint { get; set; } = "";
    public string PrivateKeyFilename { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Then I got this in Program.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    // access the built service pipeline
    public IServiceProvider Provider => provider;

    // access the built configuration
    public IConfiguration? Configuration { get; }

    public Startup()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                            .Build();

        // instantiate services
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // configure logging
        services.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.AddDebug();
            builder.AddNLog("nlog.config");
        });

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("appSettings"));

        // add necessary services
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<AppSettings, AppSettings>();
        services.AddScoped<Program, Program>();

        // build the pipeline
        provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

But when I try to read from SFTP within appSettings I only get empty string values.
Here is my code when I do some validation on appSettings values:

```
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;

    if (_appSettings.Value.LogRetention <= 0)
        Error += "appSettings.LogRetention value must be greater than 0.<br />";

    if (_appSettings.Value.DefaultFileRetention <= 0)
        Error += "appSettings.DefaultFileRetention value must be greater than 0.<br />";

    if (_appSettings.Value.SFTP.Host == "")
        Error += "appSettings.SFTP.Host cannot be empty.<br />";
```

This same code did not return any error in .NET Core 6 (either Debug or Release mode). Now with .NET Core 7 it works fine in Debug mode but in Release mode `_appSettings.Value.SFTP.Host` is empty.

My Publishing profile specifies:

> ```
> Configuration = Release | Any CPU
> Target Framework = net7.0
> Deployment mode = Self-contained
> Target runtime = win-x64
> ```

I just cannot see what's wrong. What changed from .NET Core 6 to .NET Core 7 that would prevent me from the getting correct appsettings values?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it would now be needed but I fixed it by configuring the second level like this in Program.cs

```
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("appSettings"));
    services.Configure<SFTPSettings>(configuration.GetSection("appSettings:SFTP"));
```